# Convert AM/PM string to hours

Tags: javascript

I have a custom array of AM/PM hours, and I need to convert them to the 24 hours and join with my date string (I need to send to server in this format: YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm so I'll just join the strings after I format the am/pm to h). This is the array:

```
time = [
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '12:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '01:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '02:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '03:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '04:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '05:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '06:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '07:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '08:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '09:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '10:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'AM',
          time: '11:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '12:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '01:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '02:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '03:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '04:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '05:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '06:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '07:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '08:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '09:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '10:00'
      },
      {
          period: 'PM',
          time: '11:00'
      }
  ];
```

I did not try anything so can't provide the sample code, do not know where to go with this. Is there some simple function that will do this? I am not using moment.js or anything, just a custom made dropdown with a for loop that writes the times from this array.

Comment: Short solution: add 12 hours to the time if the period is PM. Long solution: always work with Date objects to begin with and construct the AM / PM string from the date when you need to render it, instead of having a seperate array with the labels. That way your dates are always in a standard format you can easily send to the server and you can change the visuals on the client any way you want.

Comment: add +12 to the time, where period is PM

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each array(time) element. In result you can add date before time in 24 hour format.

```
function convertTimeFormat(time){
    if(time.period === 'AM'){
        return time.time;   
    } 
    else {
        var t = parseInt(time.time.split(":")[0], 10) + 12;
        return t.toString() + ":" + time.time.split(":")[1];
    }
}

for (var i=0; i < time.length; i++) {
   console.log(convertTimeFormat(time[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way would be to use the `Date` object:

```js
const time = [{
    period: 'AM',
    time: '12:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '01:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '02:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '03:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '04:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '05:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '06:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '07:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '08:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '09:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '10:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'AM',
    time: '11:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '12:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '01:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '02:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '03:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '04:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '05:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '06:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '07:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '08:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '09:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '10:00'
  },
  {
    period: 'PM',
    time: '11:00'
  }
];

function convertTo24HourFormat(timeObject) {

  if (timeObject.period === 'PM') {

    // Create a date objct and add 12 hours.
    let date = new Date(`1970-01-01T${timeObject.time}:00`);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + 12);

    // Cut out the time string
    return date.toTimeString().substring(0, 5);
  } else {

    // Return the time as it is.
    return timeObject.time;
  }
}

time.forEach(timeObject => console.log(`${timeObject.time} ${timeObject.period} > ${convertTo24HourFormat(timeObject)}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your array and on each element you can use following function to convert 12Hour to 24Hour

Give parameters as follows :
format = "24" and str = 1:00 PM (concat period and time)

```
function ConvertTimeformat(format, str) {
    var time = $("#starttime").val();
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
    if (AMPM == "PM" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "AM" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
    var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
    alert(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
}
```

You can refer here : http://jsfiddle.net/L2y2d/1/